# Momentjs change UTC time to user's local time

Tags: momentjs

I'm having trouble converting the server time to my browser's local time using moment js. For example, the server sends back time in the format **2017-07-07T02:34:39-04:00**.

```
// prints "Friday, July 7th 2017, 2:34:39 am"
moment('2017-07-07T02:34:39-04:00').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')

// prints "Friday, July 7th 2017, 2:34:39 am" 
moment('2017-07-07T02:34:39-04:00').local().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```

What I need to do is convert that datetime to the user's browser time. In the above example case, it should be "**Thursday, July 6th 2017, 10:34:39 pm**"

Comment: Which version of moment are you using? I can't reproduce the issue with lastest version (`2.18.1`), your code gives the right value in my local timezone.

Comment: Momentjs version 2.18.1

Comment: Ok, which is your local timezone? Again, I see no issue with your code `'2017-07-07T02:34:39-04:00'` is parsed as `2017-07-07T06:34:39.000Z` (UTC), that is `1499409279000` in milliseconds since the Unix Epoch.

Comment: I'm in New york/USA, and I need to show the time in relation to that. So in the example, I need `2017-07-07T02:34:39-04:00` to format into `Thursday, July 6th 2017, 10:34:39 pm`

Comment: Note that `-04:00` is the offset from UTC. I suggest reading [timezone tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) to learn more about timezone. If you want to subtract time from a moment object you can use [`subtract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) but it is completely unrelated with time offsets.